# Angular http request

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, httprequest

When I send an http post request, I get two errors. This request runs in postman. I have CORS enabled in my asp net core app.
register.component:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { User } from '../../interfaces/user';
import { AccountService } from '../../services/account.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _accountService: AccountService) { }



  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  register(ngForm: NgForm) {
    let response = this._accountService.register(ngForm);
    response.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

And account.service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../interfaces/user';

@Injectable()
export class AccountService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private _domain: string = window.location.origin;

  public register(ngForm: NgForm): Observable<object> {
    let userCred = ngForm.value as JSON;
    return this.http.post(this._domain + "/api/account/register", JSON.stringify(userCred));
  }
}
```

Errors:
[image: Errors]

Comment: What if you send `userCred` without serialising it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add header options

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
}
  let userCred = ngForm.value as JSON;
    return this.http.post(this._domain + "/api/account/register", JSON.stringify(userCred),httpOptions );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. When my asp net core application returns a status of 409 for example, I get a 409 error in the console. Can it be turned off?

Comment: try return Empty of rxjs in catchError callback function

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this. May have postman settings issues

```
You need to set the content-type in postman as JSON (application/json).
Go to the body inside your POST request, there you will find the raw option.
Right next to it, there will be a drop-down, select JSON (application.json).
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are required to set the content-type as shown in the following code block:

```
public register(ngForm: NgForm): Observable<object> {
  let userCred = ngForm.value as JSON;
  const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})     
  return this.http.post(this._domain + "/api/account/register",  
  JSON.stringify(userCred), httpOptions); 
}
```